# function that adds to the first index of a tuple in list using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a function that takes in a list of tuple and a int. The int is then added the the index 1 of each tuple with in the list. Using list comprehension. How can i achieve that? Assuming that i always have an int in the first index and the size of tuple is len = 3

```
foo(lst, x):
>>> ret = [('hello', 2, 5), ('world', 10, 2)]
>>> foo(ret, 5)
[('hello', 7, 5), ('world', 15, 2)]
```

Comment: So the tuple can have length one?

Comment: No, the len of tuples is always 3. Sorry

Answer (score 4):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
ret = [('hello', 2, 5), ('world', 10, 2)]


def foo(r, n):
    return [e[:1] + (e[1] + n,) + e[2:] for e in r]


print(foo(ret, 5))
```

**Output**

```
[('hello', 7, 5), ('world', 15, 2)]
```

**Explanation**

The fundamental part is how to create the new tuple, so `e[:1]` gets everything before index 1 (as a tuple), then the expression `(e[1] + n,)` creates a tuple of 1 element with the new value and the get the rest of the tuple using `e[2:]`. Note that you cannot change the value of an element of a tuple because tuples are immutable.

**UPDATE**

If the length of the tuple is always three you could also do the following:

```
def foo(r, n):
    return [(a, n + b, c) for a, b, c in r]
```

Comment: oh ok, so e[:1] you are taking all the values at index 1 then adding n?

Comment: @Errick-MichaelSantos Added an explanation e[:1] gets everything before index 1 not including the value at index 1.

Comment: I see. Thank you, if then what would i do if i were trying to return the sum of 7 and 15? would sum function come to play here?

Comment: @Errick-MichaelSantos Yes, you could do something like this `sum(e[1] for e in ret)`.